# Laravel 5.1 Timezone, Timestamp and System time is different. What could go wrong? Any solution please

Tags: laravel, timezone, timestamp, systemtime

I have this in my routes.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

but it doest work.

Answer (score 5):

Edit your application timezone in config/app.php

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Manila',
```